# Copy text button not working, I keep getting things saying that blank is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

so I’m trying to make a button that copy’s the paragraph tag with the ID of “n” onto the clipboard, but I keep getting errors saying that select is not a function, and other things are not a function, what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body, html {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font: Arial 14px;
}
</style>


<script>
function n() {

var ntext = document.getElementById("n");

ntext.select(); 
ntext.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);

document.execCommand("copy");

alert("could be copied")

}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<input>

<button onclick="n()">
  Click
</button>

<p id="n">
ee
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That only works on input fields. For you, since you are copying from an paragraph, you can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <script>
         function CopyToClipboard(id){
         var r = document.createRange();
         r.selectNode(document.getElementById(id));
         window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
         window.getSelection().addRange(r);
         document.execCommand('copy');
         window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
         }
      </script>
      <p id="sample">Hello World</p>
      <a href="#" onclick="CopyToClipboard('sample');return false;">Copy Text</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can just edit this now to your preference.

Source:
https://edupala.com/javascript-clipboard/